# Generate current calendar year months and future calendar year months from 1 date in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date, datetime

I have the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

last_day_of_current_year = datetime.now().date().replace(month=12, day=31)


with open(("mtn_mtx.txt").lower(), "r") as rfile:
    next(rfile)

    for line in rfile:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        line = line.upper()
        line = line.split('\t')

        firstcoupondate = (line[5])

        month_list = [i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for i in pd.date_range(start=firstcoupondate, end=last_day_of_current_year, freq='MS')]

        print(month_list)
```

This allows me to feed in a date (firstcoupondate) from a file and populate the future months between the firstcoupondate and the last day of the current year. However, I would like to adapt this code to only produce all 12 months of the current year only and not the year of the firstcoupondate.

For example if I feed in the following firstcoupondate from my file : '2020-02-05' my above code will produce the following list:

['2020-03-01', '2020-04-01', '2020-05-01', '2020-06-01', '2020-07-01', '2020-08-01', '2020-09-01', '2020-10-01', '2020-11-01', '2020-12-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01', '2021-04-01', '2021-05-01', '2021-06-01', '2021-07-01', '2021-08-01', '2021-09-01', '2021-10-01', '2021-11-01', '2021-12-01']

As you can see all the dates are showing the first day of each month which is incorrect also I'm missing the first 2 dates of January/Feburary ('2020-01-05', '2020-02-05'), so any firstcoupondate I feed in my code just won't populate the equivalent previous months date for the current year, the output I want instead of the above list of dates when feeding in '2020-02-05' should be :

['2021-01-05', '2021-02-05', '2021-03-05', '2021-04-05', '2021-05-05', '2021-06-05', '2021-07-05', '2021-08-05', '2021-09-05', '2021-10-05', '2021-11-05', '2021-12-05']

Moreoever, some firstcoupondate's I feed in have a year in the future, so if I have date '2025-04-12' I would like to then populate same as above (all 12 months) but for the year within the firstcoupondate I feed in for example firstcoupondate = '2025-04-12' I would like to generate the following list of months:

['2025-01-12', '2025-02-12', '2025-03-12', '2025-04-12', '2025-05-12', '2025-06-12', '2025-07-12', '2025-08-12', '2025-09-12', '2025-10-12', '2025-11-12', '2025-12-12']

Comment: what are you trying to get from the file?  the day of month you are interested in from 5th token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a reproducible example.  Generated what I believe to be data similar to what you find in your tab-delim file.

The key parts

1. define a function
2. use in file reading context
3. use in pandas context

```
import random
import datetime as dt
from pathlib import Path

s = 5
coupondates = [dt.date(2019 + random.randint(0,4), random.randint(1,12), random.randint(1,28)) for _ in range(s)]

cd = pd.DataFrame({
    "A":np.random.choice(["A","B","C"], s),"B":np.random.choice(["A","B","C"], s),
    "C":np.random.choice(["A","B","C"], s),"D":np.random.choice(["A","B","C"], s),
    "E":np.random.choice(["A","B","C"], s),
    "coupondate": coupondates
             })

p = Path.cwd().joinpath("mtn_mtx.txt")

ye = pd.to_datetime("now").replace(month=12, day=31)
cd.to_csv(p, sep="\t", index=False)

def drng(d):
    n = pd.to_datetime("now")
    s = n.replace(month=1, day=1) if d < n else d.replace(month=1, day=1)
    e = n.replace(month=12, day=31) if d<n else d.replace(month=12, day=31)
    return list((pd.date_range(s,e, freq="MS") + pd.DateOffset(days=d.day-1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))



# file solution
with open(p) as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip("\n").upper().split("\t")
        print(line[5], drng(pd.to_datetime(line[5])))

# pandas solution
df = pd.read_csv(p, sep="\t")
df.coupondate = pd.to_datetime(df.coupondate)
df = df.assign(allcd=df.coupondate.apply(drng))

print(df.to_markdown())
```

#### output from file loop

```
2019-01-21 ['2021-03-21', '2021-04-21', '2021-05-21', '2021-06-21', '2021-07-21', '2021-08-21', '2021-09-21', '2021-10-21', '2021-11-21', '2021-12-21']
2020-10-22 ['2021-03-22', '2021-04-22', '2021-05-22', '2021-06-22', '2021-07-22', '2021-08-22', '2021-09-22', '2021-10-22', '2021-11-22', '2021-12-22']
2020-11-19 ['2021-03-19', '2021-04-19', '2021-05-19', '2021-06-19', '2021-07-19', '2021-08-19', '2021-09-19', '2021-10-19', '2021-11-19', '2021-12-19']
2023-12-22 ['2023-01-22', '2023-02-22', '2023-03-22', '2023-04-22', '2023-05-22', '2023-06-22', '2023-07-22', '2023-08-22', '2023-09-22', '2023-10-22', '2023-11-22', '2023-12-22']
2020-10-06 ['2021-03-06', '2021-04-06', '2021-05-06', '2021-06-06', '2021-07-06', '2021-08-06', '2021-09-06', '2021-10-06', '2021-11-06', '2021-12-06']
```

#### output from pandas

|  | A | B | C | D | E | coupondate | allcd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | C | B | A | C | C | 2019-01-21 00:00:00 | ['2021-03-21', '2021-04-21', '2021-05-21', '2021-06-21', '2021-07-21', '2021-08-21', '2021-09-21', '2021-10-21', '2021-11-21', '2021-12-21'] |
| 1 | B | A | B | A | C | 2020-10-22 00:00:00 | ['2021-03-22', '2021-04-22', '2021-05-22', '2021-06-22', '2021-07-22', '2021-08-22', '2021-09-22', '2021-10-22', '2021-11-22', '2021-12-22'] |
| 2 | B | C | C | A | A | 2020-11-19 00:00:00 | ['2021-03-19', '2021-04-19', '2021-05-19', '2021-06-19', '2021-07-19', '2021-08-19', '2021-09-19', '2021-10-19', '2021-11-19', '2021-12-19'] |
| 3 | B | C | C | C | A | 2023-12-22 00:00:00 | ['2023-01-22', '2023-02-22', '2023-03-22', '2023-04-22', '2023-05-22', '2023-06-22', '2023-07-22', '2023-08-22', '2023-09-22', '2023-10-22', '2023-11-22', '2023-12-22'] |
| 4 | A | B | A | A | B | 2020-10-06 00:00:00 | ['2021-03-06', '2021-04-06', '2021-05-06', '2021-06-06', '2021-07-06', '2021-08-06', '2021-09-06', '2021-10-06', '2021-11-06', '2021-12-06'] |

Comment: Thanks, however not quite what i need yet, if the year of the coupondate fed in is in the past or present I want to see all 12 months of the current year populated as in now 2021 but if the coupondate fed in is in the future then I want to see all 12 months of that year populated for example 2023 all 12 months of 2023.

past/present coupondate fed in:  '2019-03-15'

output example needed:

['2021-01-15', '2021-02-15', '2021-03-15', '2021-04-15', '2021-05-15', '2021-06-15','2021-07-15', '2021-08-15', '2021-09-15', '2021-10-15', '2021-11-15' ,'2021-12-15']

Thanks in advance

Comment: ok - have updated if I understand your logic correctly now

Comment: This is so close, but needs to show all 12 months like thiis output:

coupondate (2019-01-21) -  ['2021-01-21', '2021-02-21', '2021-03-21', '2021-04-21', '2021-05-21', '2021-06-21', '2021-07-21', '2021-08-21', '2021-09-21', '2021-10-21', '2021-11-21', '2021-12-21']

The output you had produced for coupondate (2019-01-21) is missing January and February from the output list '2021-01-21', '2021-02-21'.

Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: `def drng(d):
    n = pd.to_datetime("now")
    s = n.replace(month=1, day=1) if d < n else d.replace(month=1, day=1)
    e = n.replace(month=12, day=31) if d<n else d.replace(month=12, day=31)
    return list((pd.date_range(s,e, freq="MS") + pd.DateOffset(days=d.day-1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
`

Comment: This is spot on what i wanted! - I've updated the code above with the new codes you supplied for anyone else that finds it useful. Thank you

Comment: By any chance, is there a way to add relative date into this? As i noticed if date fed in is end of January for example 2021-01-29 then February's date turns into start of march 2021-03-01 instead of last day in February which would be 2021-02-28